# How to update the RPM version?

Tags: linux, packaging, release-management, rpm, rpm-spec

How to update a RPM version? Shall i just update it in my spec file and re-build the entire package?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Better suited for the super user site, perhaps?

Comment: @Lars: Packaging is part of the programming process.

Comment: @Lars: After programming comes the RPM packaging so that the end user can use it.

Comment: @Lars: And that is why i have put the tags as such. Please check the tags.

Comment: I vote on this being a topic of programming, too. Imho, it fits less to super user or server fault. Packaging also often needs some scripting.

Comment: @phresnel and Ignacio: Glad there are people like you :)

Comment: Packaging is sort-of related to programming, I agree (being a Debian developer for over a decade, I can't really disagree). However, upgrading system software such as RPM is not part of programming, any more than upgrading the compiler, text editor, browser, or shell is, and those are all also integral parts of the programming environment. (But I seem to have misunderstood the question, perhaps.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be the first step, yes. You may also have to download the new source. And don't forget to reset the Release back to 1.

Comment: Did not understand, what you mean by: "And don't forget to reset the Release back to 1." I have a package 2.4, have to change it to 2.4_1.

Comment: Is it required? My first had 2.4-060007. I added a source, and was told to make it to 2.4_1. So can't i make it 2.4_1-060007?

Comment: The earlier version (before my source update) had that release number.

Comment: Yeah... if you can't answer *why* then it can't be that important. Reset to 1.

Comment: ok..thanks, i got ur point. You mean it should continue 2.4_1-00001, 2.4_1-00002..like that. Let me also confirm the same with my lead once before i start :)

Comment: Last question...Will this also update the version in readme? Or readme needs to be created a patch and all and update?

Comment: For readme update i saw, we have to untar the tarball in SOURCES, and update there. Because there is no separate patch created for README version update.